# Why is the array not being sorted?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, constructor

I'm attempting to incorporate this logic based code with the quicksort into my main program (Not shown here). The program basically generates 2d array values, and proceeds to print them out on the screen. The dim variable serves as the amount of dimensions in this code (I.e 3D) Since there are X,Y,Z coordinates. I'm having trouble understanding if this is the correct way to go about sorting this array using the [dim]. Any constructive/helpful input would be appreciated.

Example output (Not sorting it) (Taken from the last bit of the code to prove each row is not sorted :

```
[[3, 1, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1, 0]]
[[4, 5, 3, 0], [4, 5, 3, 0], [2, 1, 1, 0], [4, 5, 3, 0], [4, 5, 3, 0], [4, 5, 3, 0], [4, 5, 3, 0], [2, 1, 1, 0], [4, 5, 3, 0], [4, 5, 3, 0]]
[[4, 1, 2, 0], [4, 1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 1, 0], [4, 1, 2, 0], [4, 1, 2, 0], [4, 1, 2, 0], [4, 1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 1, 0], [4, 1, 2, 0], [4, 1, 2, 0]]
```

The actual program

```
 //import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
public class MyQuickSort {
private static int a[][] = new int [10][4];
private static int dim = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
       a[i][0] = (int)(Math.random () * 6) +1 ;
       a[i][1] = (int)(Math.random () * 6) +1 ;
       a[i][2] = (int)(Math.random () * 6) +1 ;

       quickSort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
      //}
     }

    }

    public static void quickSort(int[][] a, int p, int r)
    {
        if(p<r)
        {
            int q=partition(a,p,r);
            quickSort(a,p,q);
            quickSort(a,q+1,r);
        }
    }

    private static int partition(int[][] a, int p, int r) {

        int x = a[p][dim];
        int i = p-1 ;
        int j = r+1 ;

        while (true) {
            i++;
            while ( i< r && a[i][dim] < x)
                i++;
            j--;
            while (j>p && a[j][dim] > x)
                j--;

            if (i < j)
                swap(a, i, j);
            else
                return j;
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int[][] a, int i, int j) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int temp = a[i][dim];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j][dim] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your swap function appears to be broken.  You are swapping a `int` with an `int[]`  I suggest you decide what you are swapping. I suspect it should be an `int[]`

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your individual numbers are non-negative single-digit integers, why not just convert your array elements to strings -- that is, `[3, 1, 1, 0]` as a string -- and quicksort them like that?  The sort order will end up being the same as if you looped through each element of the above individually and compared the numerical values.

Comment: I used 10 as an example, later on in my program, the user will have the option of entering the range of the digits he wishes to use and the number of points he wants to generate.

Comment: And isn't that what I'm doing on here : System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));

Comment: How would I go about doing that exactly?

Comment: Add leading zeroes so all of your numbers are fixed length. :)  Barring that, you're right: my way won't work if your use cases extend beyond what you posted in the question.

Comment: My first comment was a response to your first comment.  In response to your third comment, even easier would be to build up a string by simply smushing all of the numbers together: `3110`.